# Query to find pairs of employees who have the same birthdate

Tags: sql

I have a table EMPLOYEE with 100 people. I would like to write a query to find pairs of employees who have the same BIRTHDATE.

The result should return EMPNO, LASTNAME and BIRTHDATE for each employee in the pair (a 6-column result table).

I thought something like that

```
SELECT  t1.EmpNo
       ,t1.LastName
       ,t1.BirthDate
        ,t2.EmpNo
        ,t2.LastName
        ,t2.BirthDate
  FROM Employee t1
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EmpNo
        ,LastName
        ,BirthDate
  FROM Employee ) t2 ON t2.BirthDate = t1.BirthDate 
  WHERE t2.EmpNo != t1.EmpNo
```

Do you think it is correct?

Comment: I try to vote but i have this message 'vote up requires 15 reputation'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just do:

```
SELECT t1.EmpNo, 
       t1.LastName, 
       t1.BirthDate, 
       t2.EmpNo, 
       t2.LastName, 
       t2.Birthdate
FROM Employee t1, Employee t2
WHERE t1.BirthDate = t2.Birthdate
AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo
```

Comment: This is in effect the same as the `INNER JOIN` proposed by user617850.

Comment: Thank you very much.if I would try to find pairs of employees who have the same BIRTHDAY date each
year. Again return EMPNO, LASTNAME and BIRTHDATE for each employee in the pair.Do you know how can i do this?

Comment: Assuming `BirthDate` is an actual date variable. The `WHERE` statement should be `WHERE DAY(t1.BirthDate) = DAY(t2.BirthDate) AND MONTH(t1.BirthDate) = MONTH(t2.BirthDate) AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo`

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct but I would remove the second select..
sub query

```
SELECT 
t1.EmpNo ,t1.LastName ,t1.BirthDate ,t2.EmpNo ,t2.LastName ,t2.BirthDate 
FROM Employee t1 
INNER JOIN Employee t2 ON t2.BirthDate = t1.BirthDate 
WHERE t2.EmpNo != t1.EmpNo
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also add the condition that `t1.EmpNo<t1.EmpNO` to avoid repetions.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer

`Select  name, date From employees Group by date of birth Having count(*)>1`;

Comment: Maybe add some explanation and formatting to your answer :)